# Organization: it or its?

Tags: possessives, personal-pronouns

When offerering to an organization I have heard that it is better to use use it as singluar (instead of they). But I am confused over this sentence:

> "In this paper, we focus on the initiative of United Nations, a non-profit organization that has been acknowledged for it great performance".

This sounds awkward to me, I would like to use *its*
What are the rules? Any suggestions?

Comment: That sounds awkward to me, too. I think it’s most likely a typo. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: This is not awkward. This is flat-out wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is in a paper that I am writing and I had it proof read a while ago, but when reading my proofs before publication I found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is incorrect; it's probably a typo as said by [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r)

*It* is a pronoun. We mostly use *it* to replace something previously stated in another sentence (objects, concepts, etc).

> *I'm going to the mall. **The mall** is probably going to be busy.*
>
> *I'm going to the mall. **It** is probably going to be busy.*

*Its* is the possessive. We use *its* when the *it* has something (similar to *he, his* and *she, her*).

> *I like going to the mall. **The mall's** parking lot is really big.*
>
> *I like going to the mall. **Its** parking lot is really big.*

Let's now look at your sentence. It mentions a great performance. Whose great performance? The United Nations'. The sentence should be changed:

> *"... for **it** great performance*" → *"... for **its** great performance"*

Comment: Thank you Kman3 for your thorough and well explained answer